# Задержка между запросами

Tags: яндекс-танк

Хочу протестировать возможности сервера, на котором крутится сайт, максимально приблизив посещаемость к среднестатистическому клиенту. Для этого нужно обеспечить задержку между запросами Uri например в 5 секунд с одного инстанса. Можно ли это организовать средствами яндекс танка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

есть 2 варианта: 
1. написать сценарий для bfg на python или для pandora на go (это [генераторы нагрузки](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#load-generators) в танке).
2. использовать дефолтный генератор нагрузки phantom с кастомным stpd файлом. Для этого вам нужно сделать ammo файл в requests формате взяв за основу [пример](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ammo_generators.html#ammo-generators) (обратите внимание что пример рассчитан на python 2). Затем [дорасставить временные метки](https://phantom-doc-ru.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-a-phantom-conf.html#ammo-stpd) указывающие в какой момент от начала старта нужно выполнить запрос - получите таким образом stpd файл. При запуске теста укажите его в конфиге вместо ammo файла опцией [stpd_file](https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core_and_modules.html#advanced-options).